# setPackagesToScan on EntityManagerFactory when Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(

Tags: java, jpa, persistent

With the following code, the EntityManagerFactory's metamodel has no packages/classes.

I'm missing the parallel `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan()` in LocalSessionFactoryBean.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, hibernateReactiveProperties());
Metamodel metamodel = emf.getMetamodel();

    Mutiny.SessionFactory reactiveSessionFactory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding class tag for each entity in persistence.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.company.EntityClassName</class>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```